# List view threshold error when capturing document set version (SP 2010)

Tags: 2010, document-library, list-view, document-set

I am working with document sets in a document library with roughly 700k items.  I am experiencing list view throttling errors while trying to create a document set version via the "Capture Version" button in the ribbon.  Each document set contains 6 documents at maximum.  List view threshold is 5k for users and 20k for administrators.

The error message is straightforward.

`The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.`

When I look up the error in the logs via the correlation Id, the log states:

`Throttled:Big list slow query. List item query elapsed time: 0 milliseconds`

Here is the CAML query that is causing the error.  This is out of the box functionality, not a custom query someone wrote.

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <IsNotNull>
                <FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser'/>
            </IsNotNull>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy Override='TRUE'>
            <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
            <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
        <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
        <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
        <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
        <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
        <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">2147483647</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Any idea why SharePoint is throwing this throttling error when trying to capture the document set version through the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not an answer because I do not know how this CAML query is related to capturing the version, but I can tell you that indeed this CAML query will not work for large lists.